# Day on Google Apps Spreadsheet's script in Google's Time Zone instead of spreadsheet time zone

Tags: date, google-apps-script

I'm using Google Apps Spreadsheet to manipulate some calendar events. I change the background color of the rows belonging to some dates (holidays).

The problem is that google scripts [use Google timezone](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/B-jrNR3t0WU), so if my spreadsheet cell contains `=Date(2016,1,1)` on the script it is interpreted as `firstCell.getValue() --> Thu Dec 31 2015 15:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)`, since my account is on Bern's timezone while Google's `GMT-0800`. Then everything I try to do with the date is off by one day; `.getDay()` or if I want to check if that row is a holiday.

What is the common approach here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Google Spreadsheet, go to File > Spreadsheet Settings and update the default timezone to that of Bern.

Also go to File menu in the script editor, choose Project settings and ensure the time zone is properly set.

Comment: it is already in that Time Zone, that's the reason I have the problem, the google script apparently is ran on PST time so I can't know reliably which day of the week is it

Comment: Also go to File menu in the script editor, Project settings and ensure the timezone is properly set.

Comment: Yeah! I didn't know this. Lovely! Post your comment into the answer so I can accept it.